# SQL vs. NoSQL database for 'tags-heavy' CRM application

Tags: sql, database, nosql, persistence, crm

I'm building a talent management CRM application and I'm having trouble choosing between a SQL or NoSQL database for my data.

The application will only have a few 'core' entities (Person, Job, Company, Interview), and will rely heavily on 'tagging' of those entities. You can add Tags and Notes to a Person, a Job, a Company, and then sort/search data by those tags.

What I learned about NoSQL is that I can just have a Person object (document) with an array of Tags and Notes, where in SQL I would need separate Tags and Notes tables and construct joins to gather all my data for a Person.

Could anyone give me some pointers on what would be the way to go for my particular scenario?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Our ERP system is based on UniData (NoSQL), it is okay for performing the standard tasks needed to do business like entering in customers, creating sales orders, invoicing etc. But when it comes to creating reports that were not originally foreseen it is quite cumbersome. The system only lets you create reports off of one table, if you need data from another table you have two options: 1. Create what is called a virtual attribute for every field you need to look up from a different table, Or write a UniBasic program to retrieve the data needed.

To meet most of our business needs on the reporting front it is more beneficial for us to export the Data to SQL and then perform reports in SQL, the result is the reports run quicker from SQL and most of the time a reporting tool can be used to create the reports - this can usually be performed by a power user as opposed to someone that has to have quite a high level of programming abilities to just build a report.

It would have been nice if it had already been in SQL in the first place.

But maybe some other NoSQL database has better functionality than UniData, that said too usually 3rd party support for NoSQL database engines comes at a higher premium because there are less specialists available than 3rd party support for SQL engines.